# Public API call to get PNR Status

Tags: android, iphone

I want to integrate Get PNR status feature in my application but dont have any api call to get it. Is there any public api call available to get current Indian Railways PNR status. If yes please provide that call and calling pattern.

Comment: till now no API is provided by IRCTC for PNR CHECKING

Comment: try https://rapidapi.com/IRCTCAPI/api/irctc1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is there you can use this url `http://pnrapi.appspot.com/+ tenDigitPNRNumber`

you can check [**here**](http://pnrapi.appspot.com/) for more

or you can go for [**erail**](https://github.com/dash1291/erail_script)

Find trains--> request URL: http://erail.in/rail/getTrains.aspx?Station_From=GWL&Station_To=NDLS&DataSource=0&Language=0

---trains pattern

---Train items

```
//Use  this regex to get the value  
reg=re.compile(r'\^\d+\~[A-Za-z0-9 ]+')

    ---train numbers from train items
        reg=re.compile(r'\d+')
    ---train names from train items
        reg=re.compile(r'[A-Za-z0-9 ]+')
```

Find Availability--> request URL : http://indiatrain.in/Rail/getAvailabilityMMT2.aspx?Train_No=11077&Station_From=GWL&Station_To=NDLS&mDay=10&mMonth=10&mYear=2011&mClass=3A&mQuota=GN&temp=1318195420696

Comment: this is not official API . it's just html parsing of other website's which provide PNR info

Comment: Agree, but this should be a way instead of not having anything.

Comment: can you add `erail` api with your answer because erail is better from other's like this is for searching train http://erail.in/rail/getTrains.aspx?Station_From=CSTM&Station_To=DAZ&DataSource=0&Language=0&Cache=true

Comment: How this site find  - [pnr-status.info](https://www.pnr-status.info/)